# Force accessing of a def

Tags: scala, overloading, shadowing

Considering

```
object A {
  def m(i: Int) = i
  val m = (i: Int) => i * 2
}
```

one gets

```
scala> A.m(2)
<console>: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both value m in object A of type => (Int) => Int
and  method m in object A of type (i: Int)Int
match argument types (Int)
       A.m(2)
         ^
```

Accessing the  `val` can be done with

```
scala> val fun = A.m
fun: (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> fun(2)
res: Int = 4
```

or

```
scala> A.m.apply(2)
res: Int = 4
```

but how would one access the `def`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is total rubbish (please, don't do this at home), but you can do it by [assigning `A` to a variable of structural type, that has only the first `m`](http://ideone.com/3AyfO).

```
val x : { def m(i:Int):Int } = A
x.m(10)
```

Comment: Neat trick! Btw, just casting also works: A.asInstanceOf[{def m(i:Int):Int}].m(10)

Comment: @Philippe: No need for `asInstanceOf` there: `(A: {def m(i:Int):Int}).m(10)`